# Sort command in not working properly in unix for sorting a csv file

Tags: linux

I have a csv file which I need to order based on the timestamp. It is the third column in the csv and I am using below commands to sort:

```
awk 'NR<2{print $_;next}{ print $_ | "sort -t, -k3.8,3.11nr -k3.1,3.3rM -k3.4rd" }'
```

This command is sorting properly when year is single, but for large data where the multiple years are present, it is putting the older ones first or in between somewhere of the csv. a sample is below:

```
data2,Send for Translation To CTM,Dec 30 2013 02:22
data1,Send for Translation To CTM,Dec 30 2013 02:20
data1,Send for Translation To CTM,Sep 30 2014 03:22
data2,Send for Translation To CTM,Oct 30 2014 03:21
```

I need to arrange the data with latest timestamp and year should go down in this order: 2014, 2013, 2012 and so on...

How can I acheive this?

Comment: Please add some example input and example output to the actual question instead of providing a link.

Comment: The first command works but you have not told it to reverse the sort order. The second one fails because you did not surround the `,` in quotes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below should work

```
 awk 'NR<2{print $_;next}{ print $_ | "sort -t, -k3.8,3.11rn -k3.1,3.3rM -k3.5,3.6rn -k3.12rd" }'
```

The 'awk' snippet passes all lines except header to the sort command.
The order of the keys is important here :

`k3.8,3.11rn` extracts the year part of the column and reverse sorts

`k3.1,3.3rM` extracts  the first 3 characters in column three to be reverse monthly sorted  and the rest we do a  reverse dictionary sort

`k3.5,3.6rn` extracts the day and reverse sort and finally we do the same for time

Comment: Could you please help me further here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26798317/linux-command-to-keep-the-latest-data-and-remove-the-other-duplicates-in-a-csv-f

Comment: It is not sorting when the multiple years are present. I am using this now: sort -t, -k3.8,3.11nr -k3.1,3.3rM -k3.4rd
But it is not working as expected. Could you please tell?

Comment: think it should be sort -t, -k3.1,3.3rM -k3.4,3.7rd -k3.8,3.11nr -k3.12rd

Comment: sorry did not understand the second time  properly i have edited the above answer and the command you have in the question should work too  remember the above solution ignores the first line so you need to use a header as the first line if there are still issues could you post a larger extract of the file like previous

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
sort -rft',' -k3 merged.csv
```

Comment: This is again not sorting properly. file is sorted in this sequence:

31st OCt, 30th Oct an then 3rd Nov data is getting arranged. I need in descending sequence like 3rd Nov, 31st oct then 30th Oct. Plus Header has also gone to the bottom !

Answer (score 0):

I will try to sort by date and then by time

```
awk -F"," '{print $3,$1,$2}' file.csv | sort -d' ' -k 1d -k 2d
```

BTW, it would be great if you just share a small section of your file. :)

Comment: Thanks, I will keep that in mind from next time :)

Though, this command is saying invalid option -- ' '