# Sort command is taking more time when trying to schedule it via cron

Tags: linux, unix, cron

I have a csv file which I am trying to sort with the below command:

```
#!/bin/bash
awk 'NR<2{print $_;next}{ print $_ | "sort -t, -k3.8,3.11nr -k3.1,3.3rM -k3.5,3.6rn -k3.12rd" }' input.csv > output.csv
```

It works properly but the issue is, it is taking **1 hour** to generate the output file when I am trying to schedule it via cron !! Though, when I am running it manually, it merely takes **5 minutes.**

This is how I am running it on cron. (script.sh is the script inside opt folder)

```
00 01 * * * /opt/script.sh
```

Could anyone explain this behavior and what needs to be done to fix it?

Comment: Aren't you overcomplicating the script by calling `sort` from within `awk`? I am sure it can be cleaner. Also, to know what is happening with your `cron`, we should see how you are calling. Edit the question to show it!

Comment: @fedorqui - Edited !! and what I need is itself complicated. Please refer to this earlier post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26782767/sort-command-in-not-working-properly-in-unix-for-sorting-a-csv-file

Comment: give a read to the "debugging crontab" section in http://stackoverflow.com/tags/crontab/info

Comment: sort [cares about locale](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/coreutils/+bug/846628) — what are the LANG/LC_\* env variables?

Comment: `(head -2 input.csv; tail -n +2 input.csv | sort -t, ...) > output.csv` would be a fair bit better than that `awk` construct, I think...

Comment: are you sure you're running it in the same manner?  Cron tends to have a different `$PATH` from your shell, so perhaps you've got `mawk` in one place and `gawk` in another.  I also highly endorse the idea of pulling `sort` out of `awk`.  @twalberg's suggestion will work if you change both instances of `2` to `1`.

Comment: @AdamKatz ah, yeah... my mistake... for some reason, I thought the OP's `awk` invocation said `NR<=2`...

Comment: @AdamKatz Sorry I am new to unix. When I did man mawk on the server it said "No manual entry for mawk" though entry is there for gawk. Do you think this is the problem that I dont have mawk on the server?

Comment: @twalberg : I tried this command (head -1 input.csv; tail -n +1 input.csv | sort -t, -k3.8,3.11nr -k3.1,3.3rM -k3.5,3.6rn -k3.12rd) but still the same result. It took 4-5 minutes when i ran it manually but again via cron, it took more than 1 hour !

Comment: @ani0710 How big is this file, and how heavily loaded is your system (related - how much CPU power does it have? Or is it an ancient 1GHz single core system with 1G memory?). What flavor/version of `cron` are you running, and, if appropriate, is it configured to run jobs with a lower-than-normal priority?

Comment: @ani0710:  If you only have one version of awk, then that is not an issue.  If it is a large file as twalberg hypothesizes, perhaps this is faster when you manually run it because you've recently read the file and it is in your disk cache.  Try running it twice (in a row) in cron; is the second run at your expected faster speed?