# How do I sort a csv file in linux according to timestamps?

Tags: linux, shell, sorting, terminal, awt

I have the following file which looks something like this:

```
XYZ,3498384,2006-04-25_12:32:45,WXZ
ABC,3498384,2006-04-25_12:33:57,DEF
NNN,3498384,2006-04-25_12:33:57,MMMM
GGGG,3874499,2006-04-25_21:14:16,TTTT
JJJJ,2518173,2006-04-25_15:12:30,PPPP
```

I have read many answers but none of them were able to sort this file. Can one suggest how should I do it?

These are the question that I have checked :
[Sort command in not working properly in unix for sorting a csv file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26782767/sort-command-in-not-working-properly-in-unix-for-sorting-a-csv-file)
But I wasn't able to understand how to use it `awk` for my problem.

Any help would be useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you are using a sensible timestamp format, you can simply use lexical sorting:

```
sort -t, -k3,3 file
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked.
I wanted to ask if there is a way to first sort it on the second attribute and than on the timestamps. Can you help?
Thanks

Comment: Sure, change the keys: because they're adjacent, you can say `-k 2,3`. If they were not, for example if you wanted to sort first by field 5 then by field 3, you would use `sort -k 5,5 -k 3,3`